# How to parse XML with xml.sax and why it's not working

Tags: python, xml, sax

I have a piece of code whitch in my opinion should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import xml.sax
import xml.sax.handler

class MyClass:
    def load_from_file(self, filename):
        class MyXmlHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
            def start_element(self, name, attrs):
                print('It\'s working!!!')

        xml.sax.parse(filename, MyXmlHandler())

app = MyClass()
app.load_from_file('/home/bps/Desktop/test.xml')
```

I'm sure that xml file is not empty, it contains many tags, but script ends silently, there is no printed strings, no error, no exception, no nothing :P
Why? I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The method name should be `startElement`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.startElement) (rather than `start_element`), or `startElementNS` if your XML uses namespaces.

Comment: Of course, Python stuck to the [SAX interface](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html) and didn't PEP-8-ify it.